# How can i render angular binding, directives and methods in innerHTML/Dynamically from S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, binding, frontend

I am working on a sass based platform which is developed in Angular and NodeJs and I want to showcase my codebase on my platform so that client can easily edit their code and can go live. But for that i have to render my code dynamically.

I tried to render angular Bindings, Directives and Methods in innerHTML but it's not working it's working as a string. If anyone has any idea how can i render angular bindings, directives, and methods dynamically in innerHTML or other ways. Please share your comments. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Template strings need to be "compiled" to be used dynamicly in a component.

Here is a working example for that :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: '<div #container></div>',
})
export class HelloComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    private environement: EnvironmentInjector
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.environement.runInContext(() => {
      // important part to allow DI with inject()

      // Define the component using Component decorator.
      const component = Component({
        selector: 'test',
        template:
          '<div>This is the dynamic template. Test value: {{test}}</div>',
        styles: [':host {color: red}'],
        providers: [{ provide: Foo, useClass: Foo }],
      })(
        class {
          private foo = inject(Foo); // DI

          constructor() {
            console.log(this.foo.rand);
          }

          test = 'some value';
        }
      );

      // Define the module using NgModule decorator.
      const module = NgModule({ declarations: [component] })(class {});

      const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(component, {
        injector: this.injector,
        ngModuleRef: createNgModuleRef(module, this.injector),
      });
      setTimeout(() => (componentRef.instance.test = 'some other value'), 2000);
    });
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qexlu4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)