# Can you use Angular's structural directives in innerHtml

Tags: html, angular, typescript, innerhtml, angular-structural-directive

I am trying to insert HTML code containing *ngIf and *ngFor directives via a DOM element's innerHtml property. Is this possible?

I don't understand how Angular renders things, so I don't know how to go about doing this. I tried using Renderer2, but this did not help.

Comment: @AluanHaddad ok, and this is not relevant?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255342/how-can-i-render-angular-binding-directives-and-methods-in-innerhtml-dynamicall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as angular template need to be compiled and `innerHTML` passes directly the string to the dom element.

The closest you can achieve but this is definitely not recommended : Create a component dynamically and pass your string as template.

This is not recommended as this requires to pull the `compiler` into the production bundle, which is heavy and also JIT components are less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need content projection, which is a way to pass HTML content (including Angular components and directives) from one component to another. Here is a quick [content projection tutorial](https://www.angulartraining.com/daily-newsletter/passing-custom-content-to-a-component-with-content-projection/):

In the parent component:

```
<app-child-component>
  This is custom content with directives:
  <p *ngIf="display"> Conditional paragraph</p>
</app-child-component>
```

And in the child component, add the following element:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

The content in the "body" of `app-child-component` will be projected (like a "cut and paste" of the HTML) into the `ng-content` element in the template of the child component.